# How to display multiple dropdown selected value with checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm selecting multiple values in the dropdown list, based on selected values that need to display below with the checkbox is checked.

For Ex:

Multiple-Dropdown-list_image
[image: Multiple-Dropdown-list_image]

below Output, I need to display like this when I selected multiple values:-

[image: dropdown-selected-values-output]

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('change','#tlist', function(){
        $('#tdata').attr('style','display:block;');
        var li = '';
        $('#tlist').each(function() {
            var values = $(this).val() ;
            $.each(values, function( index, value ) {
                var li = $('<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="dfield[]" id="' + value + '" value="' + value + '"  checked/><label class="custom-control-label blue" for="' + value + '">' + value + '</label>');
                  $('#tdata').append(li);
            });
        });
    });
```

But here I'm getting output like this why? I have selected only 3 values so I need to display only 3 selected values. But it's showing some repeated values

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Dropdown-selected-value-Output]

Comment: Include your code, don't post images of your code.

Comment: You replace the contents of #tdata (repeatedly) with a single LI in the last code line.  Consider jQuery `append` instead of `html`.

Comment: @James , I Updated my code as you told but it's showing repeated values. I have posted my output please check once

Comment: I think you didnt check already appended value, or you can remove all the appended data, bcs your current code will check every time someone click on the check box and append it but never check if a value already appended or remove before append a new one

Comment: Hi, which plugin are you using for select-box ?

Comment: @DaffaAkbari - Yes I removed the already appended value before my loop start but still is showing same

Comment: @Swati - Select2

Comment: Update your jquery code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w2Lft3x1/)

Comment: @Swati - I updated my jquery code but the selected values are not displaying

Comment: Working fine for [me](https://jsfiddle.net/d6mwfvn0/)

Comment: @Swati - Yes It's working fine now Thanks a lot